# suggestion of function prototypes in Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, intellisense, eclipse-cdt

Is there any functionality in Eclipse which would generate empty function implementations by their prototypes in the included headers ?

That is say I create some *.c file and write `#include something.h` in it, and I want Eclipse to suggest/generate empty functions which prototypes are defined in something.h.
Or at least could intellisense auto-complete function declarations (from something.h) ? Or I want too much ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing available in current Eclipse is the menu option Source/Implement method.

Which is, admittedly, not all that close. See:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/C_editor_enhancements/Source/header_synchronization

You could also look at an external tool like

http://www.radwin.org/michael/projects/stubgen/

Comment: Very thanks. BTW Source/Implement window is empty for unknown reason, maybe a bug or something...       An external tool is good option, thanks.